# Google Visualization with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

I'm curious if I can inject PHP code to the datatable of google visualization instead of using JSON strings.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows(
<?php

some PHP code that echoes the same format like this 
[['Mushrooms', 3],['Onions', 1],['Olives', 1],['Zucchini', 1],['Pepperoni', 2]]

?>);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make events on google visualization. Any help/suggestions is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean something like `data.addRows( '<?php json_encode( $my_array ) ; ?>' );` ?

Comment: yeah..i guess..jsut any php code that will show the same format required by google viz

Answer (score 0):

@scibuff has the right idea.

```
$my_array = array(
                  array('Mushrooms',3),
                  array('Onions',1),
                  array('Olives',1),
                  array('Zucchini',1),
                  array('Pepperoni',2)
);
echo json_encode( $my_array );
```

will give you `[["Mushrooms",3],["Onions",1],["Olives",1],["Zucchini",1],["Pepperoni",2]]`